# Avatars aren't loading, with a status 301 (permanently moved) response

Tags: bug, profile-picture

Some avatars (including my own) aren't loading anymore, and instead I get a transparent box. This occurs particularly after I refresh a page.

In my developer tools network tab, every request for an `i.stack.imgur.com` avatar seems to get a response of 301 (permanently moved) without content, which might explain why those avatars don't load up.

Related: [Is imgur currently down?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313779/is-imgur-currently-down)

Comment: dude, the whole imgur is down for me.

Answer (score 5):

I'm pasting the headers of a request here, too long for a comment. It's an infinite redirect, Firefox aborts after about 20 with "The page isn’t redirecting properly".

```
GET /bv54Xm.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: i.stack.imgur.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: (redacted)
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Date: Tue, 07 Aug 2018 19:19:49 GMT
Expires: Tue, 14 Aug 2018 19:19:49 GMT
Location: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bv54Xm.jpg
Server: nginx
Age: 2955
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 3fcf791d8ee7abab9c778dfe6fea5b7f.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: yc5K9NR1u1K1-ckd-EUjGRmLq5MhViMNKzKpNYAN19ADxBA66Fw_eg==
```

Edit: fixed for me as of 2018-08-08 15:00 UTC, I understand other people still have issues.

Comment: That explains why I had a couple of dozen requests for the same avatar in my network tab.

Answer (score 3):

**Update** Seems that the Avatar situation came back now that I checked again, 3 hours after...

---

<s>Just right now I can see the avatars are back again on my *Firefox*. Perhaps it will appear to others after the cache takes some time:</s>

[image: if you can read this something is not ok]

Comment: I'm still seeing a failure of images and avatars to load, as well as errors when directly navigating to stack.imgur.com: https://i.imgur.com/Q1DlhKu.png

Comment: @Tim is that on chrome? Mine was on Firefox

Comment: Chrome, Edge and IE. Chrome and Edge show the "too many redirects" error when directly opening an image.

Comment: @Tim I see ... I'll keep posted to see how this evolves (thanks for the edits on my question BTW :)

Comment: After CTRL+F5, still the same (FF): https://i.imgur.com/izygDxs.png Probably related to Cloudflare?

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Now, I again see the avatar problem, updated answer

Comment: [Nick doesn't seem to be happy at the moment](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1026970480656478208) :O

Comment: Can't see neither avatars nor images.

Comment: @egreg seems to be erratic behavior. Sometimes I see sometimes not