# i.stack.imgur seems to be down

Tags: support, imgur

All images loaded through the Stack Exchange Imgur API seem to be not working (and the webpage doesn't load either):

[image]

When I go to the actual image link I get:

[image]

imgur.com still works.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313775/332286